# Carousel no material-ui

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web, react, front-end

Como fazer o `carousel` de imagens no material-ui?

Estou utilizando essa biblioteca juntamente com React para front-end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, segue código para fazer um carousel de imagens no Material-ui seguindo o padrão da documentação deles.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import MobileStepper from '@material-ui/core/MobileStepper';
    import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
    import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    import KeyboardArrowLeft from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowLeft';
    import KeyboardArrowRight from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowRight';
    import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';
    import { autoPlay } from 'react-swipeable-views-utils';

    const AutoPlaySwipeableViews = autoPlay(SwipeableViews);

    const tutorialSteps = [
      {
        label: 'San Francisco – Oakland Bay Bridge, United States',
        imgPath:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537944434965-cf4679d1a598?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=250&q=60',
      },
      {
        label: 'Bird',
        imgPath:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538032746644-0212e812a9e7?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=250&q=60',
      },
      {
        label: 'Bali, Indonesia',
        imgPath:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537996194471-e657df975ab4?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=250&q=80',
      },
      {
        label: 'NeONBRAND Digital Marketing, Las Vegas, United States',
        imgPath:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518732714860-b62714ce0c59?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=250&q=60',
      },
      {
        label: 'Goč, Serbia',
        imgPath:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512341689857-198e7e2f3ca8?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=250&q=60',
      },
    ];

    const styles = theme => ({
      root: {
        maxWidth: 400,
        flexGrow: 1,
      },
      header: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 50,
        paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
      },
      img: {
        height: 255,
        display: 'block',
        maxWidth: 400,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        width: '100%',
      },
    });

    class SwipeableTextMobileStepper extends React.Component {
      state = {
        activeStep: 0,
      };

      handleNext = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          activeStep: prevState.activeStep + 1,
        }));
      };

      handleBack = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          activeStep: prevState.activeStep - 1,
        }));
      };

      handleStepChange = activeStep => {
        this.setState({ activeStep });
      };

      render() {
        const { classes, theme } = this.props;
        const { activeStep } = this.state;
        const maxSteps = tutorialSteps.length;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.header}>
          <Typography>{tutorialSteps[activeStep].label}</Typography>
        </Paper>
        <AutoPlaySwipeableViews
          axis={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'x-reverse' : 'x'}
          index={activeStep}
          onChangeIndex={this.handleStepChange}
          enableMouseEvents
        >
          {tutorialSteps.map((step, index) => (
            <div key={step.label}>
              {Math.abs(activeStep - index) <= 2 ? (
                <img className={classes.img} src={step.imgPath} alt={step.label} />
              ) : null}
            </div>
          ))}
        </AutoPlaySwipeableViews>
        <MobileStepper
          steps={maxSteps}
          position="static"
          activeStep={activeStep}
          className={classes.mobileStepper}
          nextButton={
            <Button size="small" onClick={this.handleNext} disabled={activeStep === maxSteps - 1}>
              Next
              {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowLeft /> : <KeyboardArrowRight />}
            </Button>
          }
          backButton={
            <Button size="small" onClick={this.handleBack} disabled={activeStep === 0}>
              {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowRight /> : <KeyboardArrowLeft />}
              Back
            </Button>
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
SwipeableTextMobileStepper.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(SwipeableTextMobileStepper);
```